# How to remove alpha channel of an image using gm?

Tags: node.js, gm

I'm looking for functionality similar to 'convert -alpha off  ' command of imagemagick, how to achieve the same using gm node module? I couldn't figure out using their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using *[gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)* node module, you can use the `-alpha` option (which is not in the [documentation](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/606) yet) this way:

```
gm('img.png')
  .options({ imageMagick: true })  // enable ImageMagick
  .alpha('Off')
  .write("out.png", function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  })
```

You could also achieve the same effect with the now obsolete `+matte` option.
This option will [turn off](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_channel) transparency channel on the image.

```
gm('img.png')
  .out("+matte")
  .write("out.png", function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: It seems to be `alpha("remove")`. That's what worked for me